# Prove that G $\rightarrow$ G/[G,G] is a functor from Grp to Ab

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Any one help me on this? I know how to show G/[G,G] is object in Ab.

How do we show the morphisms?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. If $f : G \to H$ is a group morphism, then $f([G,G]) \subseteq [H,H]$.
2. The natural map $ab \circ f: G \to H^{ab}$ sends the commutator of $G$ to zero. Show that this implies there is a unique map from $G^{ab} \to H^{ab}$ making the relevant diagram commute.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your functor $F$. I'll outline an approach, you can fill in details.

$\textrm{Id}: G \to G$ factors to a map $G/[G,G] \to G$ and then we can project to obtain a morphism $F(
\textrm{Id}): G/[G,G] \to G/[G,G]$. You must check this new map is indeed the identity morphism on AbGp.

Let $f: G \to H$, $g: H \to J$ be morphisms. $F(f \circ g) : G/[G,G] \to J/[J,J]$ is constructed by the same mechanism used for the identity map above, but instead on $g \circ f: G \to J$. We have a similar construction for $F(g) \circ F(f)$. In my opinion, the easiest way to check the morphisms are equivalent is to evaluate them at a point, i.e. show $F(f \circ g)(x) = F(g) \circ F(f)(x)$ for $x \in G$.